# DetailsView nested in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I tried to look "all over the internet" for this and can't find anything decent. So far I have have details showing to the side or underneath the GridView. When the user clicks a row, details from that row populate DetailsView.

I need to make it so the selected row expands with DetailsView.

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe someone already done this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following links to your requirement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972814.aspx

http://asp.net-informations.com/detailsview/detailsview-gridview.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

Comment: None of your links provide an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)